# tensorflow: works well in one-GPU computer but Out of Memory in two-GPU computer

Tags: python, tensorflow, multi-gpu

Before I installed the second graphics card, I had successfully trained a model which is VGG-11 architecture using tensorflow and a single GPU that has 6GB memory. But I got OOM error when I installed the second graphics card and ran the same code(allow_growth=True and no tf.device() used).

My understanding is that my second card(GPU:0) has 8GB memory and TF would use my "device:gpu:0" as default to do computation when I did not use tf.device() to specify any device. And the memory should be enough because 8GB > 6GB.

Then I tried to use CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 to block one and ran the same code. TF worked successfully.

What is the problem?

Comment: Assuming that this is SLI, memory will match the smallest GPU not the 8GB one

Comment: The old graphics card do not support SLI. But no matter what, I can't understand why TF throws an OOM error because this is not a huge model and it can be succeessfully built in a 6GB single-GPU system.